# Automorphisms of a torus

Tags: lie-groups

Why is the set of automorphism of a n-dimensional torus T (also denoted $T^n$) is $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ i.e the set of invertible matrices with integral coefficients?

In the book by Brocker and Dieck- Representations of Compact Lie Groups, the crucial step for proving this goes as follows-

> If there is a homomorphism $\phi:T^n\to S^1$, then it induces the diagram
>
> $$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}  \mathbb{Z}^n @>{\hookrightarrow}>> \mathbb{R}^n @>{D\phi}>> \mathbb{R}\\@VVV @VVV @VVV \\  \mathbb{Z} @>{\hookrightarrow}>> T^n @>{\phi}>> S^1 \end{CD}$$
> which gives the result that $$D\phi(v_1,...,v_n)= \sum n_iv_i$$ where $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$; where the vertical maps are projections.

Q.1. How is the above formula for $D\phi$ inferred?

Other than that argument, I have managed to show that $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})\subset Aut(T^n)$. But how to show the other inclusion? That is,

Q.2. Given an automorphism $\phi$ of $T^n= \mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$, show that there exist a map $\Phi$ $\in$ $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\pi \circ\Phi = \phi$ , where $\pi:R^n\to T^n$ is the projection.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you understand what the vertical arrows in this diagram represent? That's the first step...

Comment: Lee Mosher : Yes. I am familiar with the concept of exponential map in a Lie group.

Comment: Well, those may be exponential maps of Lie groups, but it's also important to understand them as quotient maps in the category of Lie groups.

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with them being covering maps, projection maps, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here we are talking about the automorphisms of a torus as a **Lie group**,
that is we want group-automorphisms of $T^n$ which are smooth (actually continuous is enough as that will imply smoothness).

Let $T^n=\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$. Let's try to find all smooth homomorphisms $F$ from $T^m$ to $T^n$. Composing with the projection
from $\mathbb{R}^m\to T^m$, $F$ induces a continuous homomorphism $\tilde F:\mathbb{R}^m\to T^n$. Every continuous map from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to a nice enough topological space lifts to its universal cover ($T^n$ is certainly nice enough) so $\tilde F$ lifts to a continuous map $\hat F$ from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. We can ensure that $\hat F(0)=0$ and then $\hat F$ is a continuous homomorphism (this can be reduced to checking in the neighbourhood of zero). Then $\hat F$ is given by a real
$m$-by-$n$ matrix. But $\hat F$ must take the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^m$ into $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Thus its entries are integers.

Conversely, an integer matrix induces a Lie group homomorphism from
$T^m$ to $T^n$ given by matrix multiplication acting on vectors.

Composing these homomorphisms just multiplies their matrices.
Therefore the endomorphisms of $T^n$ which are invertible come
from precisely the invertible $n$-by-$n$ matrices.

Comment: "Then $\hat F$ is given by a real $m$-by-$n$ matrix. But $\hat F$ must take the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^m$ into $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Thus its entries are integers." How? Integral entries in a matrix will cause the matrix to fix the $\mathbb{Z}^n$, but how to show the converse?

Comment: Oh! I got it...

Comment: Why is $\hat{F}(0)=0$?

Answer (score 2):

To put it in a concise answer:

A.1: If for some $i$, $n_i \in \mathbb{R}$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}$, then the corresponding unit vector will map to $$D\phi(0,...,0,e_i,0,..0)=\sum_{i\neq j} n_j. 0 + n_i.e_i = n_i.e_i$$ which will not be sent to $\mathbb{Z}$. Hence the entries of the matrix must be integers.

A.2: (As detailed above) Any homomorphism $\phi \in Aut(T^n)$ can be lifted to $Aut(\mathbb{R}^n)$, because of the **lifting property of universal cover**. (Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the universal cover of $T^n$). Therefore $$Aut(T^n)\subset Aut(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
Hence the automorphism is given by a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your first sentence I want to add a further reference [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154211/the-group-of-all-biholomorphic-group-automorphisms-of-complex-tori), where we see that the automorphism group of $T^n=\mathbb{R}^n/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is a lattice (here $\mathbb{Z}^n$) is isomorphic to the automorphisms of the lattice $\Lambda$, which is the group of linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ mapping $\Lambda$ to $\Lambda$. So the group is
$$
Aut(T^n)=Aut(\mathbb{Z}^n)=GL_n(\mathbb{Z}).
$$

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant why $Aut(T^n)=Aut(\mathbb{Z}^n)$, when they say "The automorphism group you describe is always equal to the group of automorphisms of the lattice "